# Animate.css issue on iphone devices

Tags: jquery, css

I have no idea why my css animation works on desktop, but doesn't on mobile. If shrink it to mobile size it works, but when I go on my Iphone 6 my truck animation doesn't work.
This animation contains [here](http://www.belava.com/t-todays_page.aspx) on 2nd slide of my slideshow.

Comment: What's the CSS code you have been trying?

Comment: im using animate.css

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that my slide show was also made with css file, and it looked like my animation was confused on mobile devices. If I would change animation for the track with any other effect it would work perfectly fine.